# Object Reference not set to an instance of an object error C# Class selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a class called `Driver` and I'm trying to five its attributes to another class, so I can use it for the Locators, but it is giving me this error on the driver from the locator.

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace AutomationTest
{
   public class BaseLocator
   {
       public static RemoteWebDriver driver;
       public static WebDriverWait wait;
       public IWebElement SearchBox => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#twotabsearchtextbox");
       public IWebElement SearchButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("span#nav-search-submit-text + input");
       public IWebElement GoToShoppingButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#nav-cart-count");
       public IWebElement GoToYourAmazonButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("a#nav-your-amazon");
   }
}
```

and I have `Driver` set up as:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace AutomationTest
{
   public class Driver
   {
       public RemoteWebDriver SetUp()
       {
           RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           return driver;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "five its attributes"?

Comment: you are not initializing driver as far as I can tell... (or "Driver")... and you never call "SetUp" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `driver`. Unless you plan on having multiple things to setup in the driver class, it's unnecessary (don't over think it).

this example initializes the `driver` object inline with the definition.

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace AutomationTest
{
   public class BaseLocator
   {
       public static RemoteWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       //public static WebDriverWait wait; //TODO: Initialize variable as above

       public IWebElement SearchBox => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#twotabsearchtextbox");
       public IWebElement SearchButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("span#nav-search-submit-text + input");
       public IWebElement GoToShoppingButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#nav-cart-count");
       public IWebElement GoToYourAmazonButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("a#nav-your-amazon");
   }
}
```

while this example initializes it via the default constructor method:

```cs
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace AutomationTest
{
   public class BaseLocator
   {
       public static RemoteWebDriver driver;
       //public static WebDriverWait wait;

       public BaseLocator()
       {
           driver = new ChromeDriver();
       }

       public IWebElement SearchBox => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#twotabsearchtextbox");
       public IWebElement SearchButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("span#nav-search-submit-text + input");
       public IWebElement GoToShoppingButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("#nav-cart-count");
       public IWebElement GoToYourAmazonButton => driver.FindElementByCssSelector("a#nav-your-amazon");
   }
}
```

If you don't need `driver` outside of the `BaseLocator` class, then you should consider making it private. Not sure it needs to be declared as a static member either.

I'm unfamiliar with Selenium, so I approached this from a C# language angle- but it should get you down the track.

recommended reading on constructors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors

Comment: Thank you very much it did work with the constructor!